# style/class file for LACUS

Tags: linguistics

Are there any linguists here who know of a style/class file for the LACUS conference? My tex-fu isn't quite good enough to make my own. The guidelines for it are [here](http://lacus.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/authorguidelines.pdf), but lacus.org doesn't seem to have any template that can be used, except a Word template for abstracts. What makes things worse, googling for "latex lacus" brings up all of these documents with "Nam lacus libero" and other Latin phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best would be to email LACUS institution (there are several emails, for example a [publication director](http://lacus.weebly.com/contact-lacus.html)) and ask there for an template. If they have no template ask them wether they can work with a `tex` file or not.

If they do not offer a LaTeX template you have to do it by your own, following the design guide.

Comment: Ah man, not only do they not have a template, but they require Word documents for submission :(

Comment: It sounded like it was because they just didn't know how to use it, or the people who were formatting the entire thing could only edit word documents.